# Convert .css file into .scss file with using current available mixing and variables

Tags: sass

My **style.scss** file has been deleted mistakenly and I don't have any backup.

In my project still **_mixins.scss** and **_variables.scss** are available.

Is it possible to generate **style.scss** again by using **style.css** file, with use of current **_mixins.scss** and **_variables.scss**?

I tried some online tool **css to scss** convert but they added new variables and mixins code, which I don't want in my current project.

May I know any **scss commands**, which can reverse **.css file into .scss** file with using current available **mixing and variables** ?

My folder structure

```
-css
 ------ style.css

-scss
 ------ _mixins.scss
 ------ _variables.scss
 ------ style.scss (by mistakenly deleted and no backup available)
```

Comment: Don't think it's possible. You can't revert mixins calls and variables usages.

Comment: You might try this http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/ And back up your work, even if its just copying the files to another directory